# Android WiFi direct feature

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am currently working on a project which includes sending files to others, e.g. as an E-Mail attachment or bluetooth. Now I want to add WiFi direct to that.

The following code returns a list of capable applications - such as bluetooth, NFC, etc... WiFi Direct does not appear there.

```
Intent shareIntent=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(selectedFile);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri);
shareIntent.setType("file/*");

Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent , "Select Sender");
                                                startActivity(chooser);
```

Is there any reason why it does not? I already found an answer on how to sent via WiFi Direct (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25638517), but I do want that feature in this selector - if possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: Android does not support the shareIntent for Wifi Direct (yet).

long answer: There could be several p2p device in the area - you need to choose an recipient (by Name or MAC). You would need to pass that along with the Intent. Right now there are apps, like superbeam that support this functionality you want. Android does not offer the high level functionality of easily sharing via shareIntent, see [this discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/48wy1j/lets_talk_about_wifi_direct/).